# Webpack file-loader with dynamic public path

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack and the file loader to resolve `import/require()` to a url. The problem is that I need a mechanism to change that url at runtime with a method that is injected into the browser. So at runtime I have a method like `window.changeAssetPath(existingPath)` that needs to be executed for each static file that is delivered to the user. I checked the configuration for the file loader and noticed that there is a setting named `postTransformPublicPath`. So I tried to use it like this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          postTransformPublicPath: (p) => { return window.changeAssetPath(p) },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

But `window` is not defined during the webpack build and so the build fails. Do you know a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to stringify the function call. So this should work:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      postTransformPublicPath: (p) => { return "window.changeAssetPath(" + p + ")" },
    }
}
```